# Docker Compose | Understanding issue, do i have to "open" ports inside of docker networks?

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

i am creating an Nextcloud Docker Container with an DB and a NGINX Https Proxy.
I want to let the containers communicate inside a docker network.
As far as i know that the containers will be accesable by their "service" name.
The NGINX Proxy have to access port 80 from the nextcloud container. So do i have to refer the container as "app:80" in the nginx config or do i have to do anything else do make it work?
Thanks for anyone who helps me :D

Here is the compose file i will use

```
version: "2"

volumes:
  nextcloud:
  db:

services:
  swag:
    image: ghcr.io/linuxserver/swag
    container_name: swag
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=Europe/London
      - URL=secret
      - SUBDOMAINS=cloud,
      - VALIDATION=http
      - EMAIL=secret
    volumes:
      - /srv/swagdocker:/config
    ports:
      - 443:443
      - 80:80
    restart: unless-stopped
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --binlog-format=ROW
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
  app:
    image: nextcloud
    restart: always
    links:
      - db
    volumes:
      - nextcloud:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=secret
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_USER=nextcloud
      - MYSQL_HOST=db
```

Comment: [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation describes this: you should be able to use the service name and the port the process in the container is listening on, without any additional setup.  There is no need to "open a port" and you do not need any particular Compose directives.  Is there a specific problem you're running into with the Compose setup you show?

Comment: no i have to know this before i run the docker-compose script because of the lets encrypt certificate.